# Log after actor system has been shutdown

Tags: scala, jvm, akka

I am using `log` method from `with ActorLogging` to make logs. I would like to make a few logs after the system is shut down, but that is not working, as I would assume it uses system for logging. What I would like to do looks like that:

```
  logger.info("Shutting down actor system.")

  context.system.shutdown()
  context.system.registerOnTermination {
    logger.info("Actor System terminated, stopping loggers and exiting.")
    loggerContext.stop()
  }
```

Are there any workarounds to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just slf4j (backed for instance by logback) directly as described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/logging.html#SLF4J).